# Magento 2 How to add Customer address attribute value under set Shipping Address on Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, magento-checkout

I have create one custom field on Customer address form and save it's value on customer address attribute in customer_address_entity_text table.

Now, When I go to Checkout Page then need to display this Custom field value under Shipping address as per default magento field value on below Place.

You can get references using the below image.
https://i.imgur.com/HQUM27V.png

Answer (score 1):

You can review the following files, which are intended to display all addresses along with their attributes.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html


vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js
```

Comment: Thanks @Harish kuril

Comment: Welcome @KevalChauhan, If my answer has resolved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks.